# When to use MongoDB or other document oriented database systems?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

We offer a platform for video- and audio-clips, photos and vector-grafics. We started with MySQL as the database backend and recently included [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home) for storing all meta-information of the files, because MongoDB better fits the requirements. For example: photos may have [Exif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) information, videos may have audio-tracks where we to want to store the meta-information of, too. Videos and vector-graphics don't share any common meta-information, etc. so I know, that MongoDB is perfect to store this unstructured data and keep it searchable.

However, we continue developing our platform and adding features. Now one of the next steps will be providing a forum for our users. The question that now arises is: use the MySQL database, which would be a good choice for storing forums and forum-posts, etc. or use MongoDB for this, too?

So the question is: when to use MongoDB and when to use a RDBMS. What would you take, mongoDB or MySQL, if you had the choice and why would you take it?

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as opinion-based when it clearly is not. There is a clear right or wrong answer here.

Answer (score 669, accepted):

In [NoSQL: If Only It Was That Easy](http://web.archive.org/web/20090828102023/http://bjclark.me/2009/08/04/nosql-if-only-it-was-that-easy/), the author writes about MongoDB:

> MongoDB is not a key/value store, it’s quite a bit more. It’s definitely not a RDBMS either. I haven’t used MongoDB in production, but I have used it a little building a test app and it is a very cool piece of kit. It seems to be very performant and either has, or will have soon, fault tolerance and auto-sharding (aka it will scale). I think Mongo might be the closest thing to a RDBMS replacement that I’ve seen so far. It won’t work for all data sets and access patterns, but it’s built for your typical CRUD stuff. Storing what is essentially a huge hash, and being able to select on any of those keys, is what most people use a relational database for. **If your DB is 3NF and you don’t do any joins (you’re just selecting a bunch of tables and putting all the objects together, AKA what most people do in a web app), MongoDB would probably kick ass for you.**

Then, in the conclusion:

> **The real thing to point out is that if you are being held back from making something super awesome because you can’t choose a database, you are doing it wrong.** If you know mysql, just use it. Optimize when you actually need to. Use it like a k/v store, use it like a rdbms, but for god sake, build your killer app! None of this will matter to most apps. Facebook still uses MySQL, a lot. Wikipedia uses MySQL, a lot. FriendFeed uses MySQL, a lot. **NoSQL is a great tool, but it’s certainly not going to be your competitive edge, it’s not going to make your app hot, and most of all, your users won’t care about any of this.**
>
> What am I going to build my next app on? Probably Postgres. Will I use NoSQL? Maybe. I might also use Hadoop and Hive. I might keep everything in flat files. Maybe I’ll start hacking on Maglev. **I’ll use whatever is best for the job.** **If I need reporting, I won’t be using any NoSQL.** If I need caching, I’ll probably use Tokyo Tyrant. **If I need ACIDity, I won’t use NoSQL.** If I need a ton of counters, I’ll use Redis. **If I need transactions, I’ll use Postgres.** **If I have a ton of a single type of documents, I’ll probably use Mongo.** If I need to write 1 billion objects a day, I’d probably use Voldemort. If I need full text search, I’d probably use Solr. If I need full text search of volatile data, I’d probably use Sphinx.

I like this article, I find it very informative, it gives a good overview of the NoSQL landscape and hype. But, and that's the most important part, it really helps to ask yourself the right questions when it comes to choose between RDBMS and NoSQL. Worth the read IMHO.

[Alternate link to article](http://markedaspertinent.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/nosql-if-only-it-was-that-easy/)

Comment: http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1016320617/mongodb-is-web-scale#

Comment: @iddqd ROFL! Man, this was hilarious. *"If you are stupid enough to totally ignore the reliability just to get benchmarks, I suggest you pipe your data to `/dev/null`, it will be very fast"* :D

Comment: Hopefully BJ Clark won't choose to use *all* those technologies in the same project. That would be a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: @PascalThivent this answer really helped a lot, you seem to know so many technologies, I wanna learn all you know men!!

Comment: The blog is no longer up, but you can view the article here: http://web.archive.org/web/20090828102023/http://bjclark.me/2009/08/04/nosql-if-only-it-was-that-easy/

Comment: "I've not used x in production, but" - *stops reading*

Comment: I think this answer probably has changed a lot since it was originally written. I agree you should use something that you are comfortable with using.  However I would highly recommend trying Mongo.  It has added a lot of things like Transactions/Rollbacks and full text searching.  The only real limitation is reporting.  They are developing charts(https://www.mongodb.com/products/charts) which at least allows making some graphical charts, but wont get you your paged excel like reports.

Answer (score 197):

After two years using MongoDb for a social app, I have witnessed what it really means to live without a SQL RDBMS.

1. You end up writing jobs to do things like joining data from different tables/collections, something that an RDBMS would do for you automatically.
2. Your query capabilities with NoSQL are drastically crippled. MongoDb may be the closest thing to SQL but it is still extremely far behind. Trust me. SQL queries are super intuitive, flexible and powerful. MongoDb queries are not.
3. MongoDb queries can retrieve data from only one collection and take advantage of only one index. And MongoDb is probably one of the most flexible NoSQL databases. In many scenarios, this means more round-trips to the server to find related records. And then you start de-normalizing data - which means background jobs.
4. The fact that it is not a relational database means that you won't have (thought by some to be bad performing) foreign key constrains to ensure that your data is consistent. I assure you this is eventually going to create data inconsistencies in your database. Be prepared. Most likely you will start writing processes or checks to keep your database consistent, which will probably not perform better than letting the RDBMS do it for you.
5. Forget about mature frameworks like hibernate.

I believe that 98% of all projects probably are way better with a typical SQL RDBMS than with NoSQL.

Comment: interesting thoughts...

Comment: On the other hand, query capabilities and the joins you describe shouldn't be an issue: if you use MongoDB then you still have to do some job to design your collections and what data you will put inside so that you won't need complex JOINs and so on. Anyways DBs are not a bottleneck and there are workarounds like Memcache for some use cases. If starting from scratch though, you might find that designing and using MongoDB is simpler and faster (as a developer working with object code, I don't need an ORM). Sure you have to write a few scripts, but actually it is not that hard and you reuse code

Comment: Most people won't use NoSQL databases for the *very specific* use-case they were created for, reinventing so many wheels afterwards. The [NoSQL vs. SQL debate](http://www.nosql-vs-sql.com/) shows that many people experience using NoSQL as if they were going back 20-30 years in time, to [pre-Codd, pre-relational, pre-SQL times](http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2013/12/11/codds-relational-vision-has-nosql-come-full-circle). Or, as Michael Stonebraker puts it: ["What Goes Around Comes Around"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.113.5640)

Comment: Is item #3, "and take advantage of only one index" still valid today?  I'm just getting into MongoDB now and it seems from what I have read/viewed so far that it can support multiple indexes?

Comment: I was with you until 5.  Why would you want to use an ORM on top of a document store?  Isn't the whole purpose of an ORM to adapt SQL to be more like a document store?

Comment: @Jeach: No, #3 is no longer true. MongoDB 2.6 introduced [index intersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/).

Comment: #2, #3, #5 are not true today anymore (I know this answer was written a long time ago). 
Also: if you end up with #1 / #4 it means you used MongoDB without knowing what it is and what it is supposed to do. Right tool for the job...

Comment: This is an opinion piece, not an answer. Most of these are obsolete anyways. "84% of statistics are made up on the spot".

Comment: This is only one side, on the other hand you have `schemaless` which is a huge benefit in today's world as many follow Agile strategy and requirement change a lot, on the other hand you have performance and scaling via sharding. reliability most of the time comes from well written code and well managed infra

Comment: This aged well :)

Answer (score 27):

> to store this unstructured data

As you said, MongoDB is best suitable to store unstructured data. And this can organize your data into document format. These RDBMS altenatives called **NoSQL** data stores ([MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB), [CouchDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchDB), [Voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/)) are very useful for applications that scales massively and require faster data access from these big data stores.

And the implementation of these databases are simpler than the regular RDBMS. Since these are simple key-valued or document style binary objects directly serialized into disk.
These data stores don't enforce the **ACID properties**, and any **schemas**. This doesn't provide any **transaction** abilities. So this can scale big and we can achieve faster access (both read and write).

But in contrast, RDBM enforces ACID and schemas on datas. If you wanted to work with structured data you can go ahead with RDBM.

I would choose **MySQL** for creating **forums** for this kind of stuff. Because this is not going to scale big. And this is a very simple (common) application which has structured relations among the data.

Comment: "I would choose mysql for creating forums kind of stuff." Really? I think things like forums would be much easier to write using a document-oriented database than a relational (if you were writing it from scratch). If you don't specifically need the features of an RDBMS, I would say go with MongoDB or a similar database for ease of use and scaling.

Comment: CouchDB has ACID support.http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/overview.html

Comment: 2018: MongoDB has ACID support as well

Answer (score 13):

Note that Mongo essentially stores JSON.  If your app is dealing with a lot of JS Objects (with nesting) and you want to persist these objects then there is a very strong argument for using Mongo.  It makes your DAL and MVC layers ultra thin, because they are not un-packaging all the JS object properties and trying to force-fit them into a structure (schema) that they don't naturally fit into.

We have a system that has several complex JS Objects at its heart, and we love Mongo because we can persist everything really, really easily.  Our objects are also rather amorphous and unstructured, and Mongo soaks up that complication without blinking.  We have a custom reporting layer that deciphers the amorphous data for human consumption, and that wasn't that difficult to develop.

Answer (score 9):

Who needs distributed, sharded forums? Maybe Facebook, but unless you're creating a Facebook-competitor, just use Mysql, Postgres or whatever you are most comfortable with. If you want to try MongoDB, ok, but don't expect it to do magic for you. It'll have its quirks and general nastiness, just as everything else, as I'm sure you've already discovered if you really have been working on it already.

Sure, MongoDB may be hyped and seem easy on the surface, but you'll run into problems which more mature products have already overcome. Don't be lured so easily, but rather wait until "nosql" matures, or dies.

Personally, I think "nosql" will wither and die from fragmentation, as there are no set standards (almost by definition). So I will not personally bet on it for any long-term projects.

Only thing that can save "nosql" in my book, is if it can integrate into Ruby or similar languages seamlessly, and make the language "persistent", almost without any overhead in coding and design. That may come to pass, but I'll wait until then, not now, AND it needs to be more mature of course.

Btw, why are you creating a forum from scratch? There are tons of open source forums which can be tweaked to fit most requirements, unless you really are creating The Next Generation of Forums (which I doubt).

Comment: thanks for your answer. integrating a forum is a mess -- we've already done this and decided to not go this way again: we do not need thousands of features but a full integration in our software.

Answer (score 7):

I would say use an RDBMS if you need complex transactions. Otherwise I would go with MongoDB - more flexible to work with and you know it can scale when you need to. (I'm biased though - I work on the MongoDB project)

Comment: Complex transactions don't work in MongoDB, but they do work in other NoSQL databases, like MarkLogic (I'm biased too since I run the developer community for MarkLogic).

Comment: Thanks for the hint to MarkLogic -- i did not know of it.

Comment: I'd like to hear from mdirolf about that. Why did MongoDB choose not to implement transactions?

Answer (score 6):

The 2 main reason why you might want to prefer Mongo are

- Flexibility in schema design (JSON type document store).
- Scalability - Just add up nodes and it can scale horizontally quite well.

It is suitable for big data applications. RDBMS is not good for big data.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen at lot of companies are using MongoDB for realtime analytics from application logs. Its schema-freeness really fits for application logs, where record schema tends to change time-to-time. Also, its [Capped Collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) feature is useful because it automatically purges old data to keep the data fit into the memory.

That is one area I really think MongoDB fits for, but MySQL/PostgreSQL is more recommended in general. There're a lot of documentations and developer resources on the web, as well as their functionality and robustness.

Answer (score 3):

You know, all this stuff about the joins and the 'complex transactions' -- but it was Monty himself who, many years ago, explained away the "need" for COMMIT / ROLLBACK, saying that 'all that is done in the logic classes (and not the database) anyway' -- so it's the same thing all over again.  What is needed is a dumb yet incredibly tidy and fast data storage/retrieval engine, for 99% of what the web apps do.

Comment: Thanks, you are raising an interesting point here. I would really be interested in Monty's explanation, because i am not sure how complex rollbacks of updates across multiple tables get in pure application logic -- i am not sure, if this is really possible?

Comment: I'm not sure the 'best' way, either.  We've always just tracked everything done to the DB, and then either allow or undo it at the application level, in code.  We've never relied upon transactions, anywhere, ever.  Mongo docs suggest using metadata to track what parts of the rollbackable transaction have occurred, what state the transaction is in, in case it breaks and needs to be rolled back.  Funny thing is, we'd already been doing that all along with MySQL and others.  It's not that much more work and it keeps the focus on what's going on, when, where and why, instead of black boxing it.

Comment: There's a note about this on the 10gen website somewhere...mentioning how 'interlock' fields, or 'ratchets' are manually used to indicate the status of a multi-step process.  Seems to me that if you zoom into the MySQL engine itself, the "block transaction" still expands out to a series of steps, no matter what; it's just that the interlocks or ratchets are done in a much smaller, faster manner than doing the tracking manually in database fields.

Comment: We've yet to find a good way to limit the MongoDB daemon - it gobbles nearly all available RAM for its index and data storage in memory, though it yields memory quickly when other procs need it.  Still, it would be nice to have a 'use_max_memory' or some other easily definable limits to make sure MongoDB doesn't run away and send the server into swap thrashing (we've seen this several times, even at most recent version).  At least MySQL accepts all kinds of definable limits and operation hints.

Comment: Not directly related, but kind-of: We were using memcached but gave up on it because of the still-unresolved Memcache/Memcached PHP driver fiasco.  We used MongoDB as a quick, temporary key:val store (for which it worked great!) until discovering how fast and easy apc_store() is.  If we find that APC is filling up with temporary crud (vs stored precompiled PHP) that we used to stach in memcached, we'll revert to MongoDB for key:val storage.

Answer (score 1):

Like said previously,
you can choose between a lot of choices, take a look at all those choices:
http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

What I suggest is to find your best combination:
MySQL + Memcache is really great if you need ACID and you want to join some tables
MongoDB + Redis is perfect for document store
Neo4J is perfect for graph database

What i do: I start with MySQl + Memcache because I'm use to, then I start using others database framework. In a single project, you can combine MySQL and MongoDB for instance !

Comment: MySQL + memcached will give you Eventual Consistency. Which i don't consider ACID in a RDMB context.