# Using Mysql with Nodejs and Express (node-mysql)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Im new to node and express and I have a question regarding 
using mysql. 
I have a login form that posts to '/login'. Im using the node-mysql 
module.

```
 app.get('/site', function(req, res){
    if (req.session.is_logged_in === true) {
        res.render('site/start', {
            title: 'News'
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    client.query('SELECT id, user_name FROM user WHERE email="' + req.body.login + '" AND password="' + Hash.sha1(req.body.password) + '"',
        function (err, results, fields) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            if (results[0]) {
                req.session.userInfo = results[0];
                req.session.is_logged_in = true;
                res.render('site/start', {
                    title: 'News'
                });
            }
            else {
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Is this a good way to do it? Can i continue this way? 
And are the sql querys escaped in some way, or do i have to write that 
functionality myself?

Last question: Im rewriting a site, and i used the mysql db. Are there 
any benefits to changing it to mongodb?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

George

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is this a good way to do it? Can i
>   continue this way? And are the sql
>   querys escaped in some way, or do i
>   have to write that functionality
>   myself?

You should sanitize your SQL query parameters first. For example by utilizing functionality of [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) module in order to prevent [SQL injection attacks](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).

> I'm rewriting a site, and i used the
>   mysql db. Are there any benefits to
>   changing it to mongodb?

In general it depends on the functionality of your site and other stuff. Try to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476295/when-to-use-mongodb-or-other-document-oriented-database-systems) question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)

node-validator looks awesome, just what i was looking for.

Thanks :)

Comment: node-mysql has escaping as well. If you use it properly, of course. https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values

Answer (score 14):

The node-mysql Client object has an escape method that can help with this. You can either call that manually, or use the form of query that accepts parameters. E.g:

```
client.query('SELECT id, user_name FROM user WHERE email=?',
    [req.body.login], ...
```

Note using the parameter method doesn't actually submit a parameterized query to mysql, it just takes care of the parameter substitution and escaping for you.

BTW, here's what the escape does:

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/lib/protocol/SqlString.js#L3

Comment: The above link is now invalid (404).

Comment: I believe Connection.query is more interesting for people using it: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/lib/Connection.js#L96

Answer (score 5):

If your site becomes more complex you might be interested in using an ORM for your MySQL stuff. Sequelize uses the node-mysql lib and manages the complete sql stuff for: http://sequelizejs.com