# Motivations for using relational database / ORM or document database / ODM

Tags: database, orm, nosql, document-database, odm

It's been a long time since I haven't created a project from scratch, and now [document-oriented databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) (as well as ODM) have become quite popular, so I have to consider them before blindly going the relational route.

Could anyone try to list the motivations / project criteria that could lead to one choice or another?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### ORM / relational database / SQL

Pros:

- well-understood, standard approach
- maps well to data with consistent structure
- maps well to data with multiple relationships between multiple entities
- has extensive join capabilities
- has transactions
- scalable to huge number of transactions per second (using MySQL Cluster, Fusion-IO, etc)

Cons:

- hard to scale to huge volume of data, if performance is also a concern
- does not map well to data with variable structure (or semi-structured)
- persisting objects requires a glue/translation layer which can be a performance bottleneck (and if done wrong also can be very verbose)

### ODM / document database / NoSQL

Pros:

- scalable to huge volume of data, and to huge numbers of relatively independent queries
- high availability, sharding, multi-master, ...
- maps well to semi-structured data
- maps well to data with more variable structure
- data model can be more flexible
- queries do not have to be translated to SQL (the native NoSQL query style may or may not be better suited for some uses, and no overhead from SQL driver/parsing/etc)
- (for object databases) maps directly to objects, no need for object-relational translation

Cons:

- often, no join (or limited version of join)
- often, no transactions (or a limited version of transactional consistency/atomicity)

### How to decide

Based on the type of data and usage patterns:

- Does the data have a uniform structure? (relational) ... or a variable/inconsistent structure? (document)
- Does typical usage read/write a single type of entity? (document) ... or a view which is composed of properties of multiple entities? (relational)
- Are transactions required? (relational) ... or no transactions needed? (document)

Based on the scaling/performance requirements:

- Huge data + few, slow, complex read/writes? (data warehousing type scenario) => relational
- Huge data + huge volume of simple read/writes? (craigslist backend type scenario) => document
- Huge data + fast, complex reads/writes? => this is difficult; either use relational and try to scale it up, or use document and try to simplify queries
- Moderate data + fast transactional writes? (banking type scenario) => relational
- Moderate data + moderate read/write? => pick any based on vendor/tool support, familiarity, etc

### References

- [When to use MongoDB or other document oriented database systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476295/when-to-use-mongodb-or-other-document-oriented-database-systems)
- [Document-Oriented Databases vs. Relational Databases, Doctrine Blog](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/document-oriented-databases-vs-relational-databases.html)
- [NoSQL: If Only It Was That Easy, BJ Clark](http://bjclark.me/2009/08/nosql-if-only-it-was-that-easy/)
- [Relational vs. Non-Relational, Josh Berkus](http://www.pgexperts.com/document.html?id=40)

(Background: I haven't done anything in this area very recently, but a few years ago I built a large system which used replicated MySQL + Sphinx, ie a relational and document hybrid)

Comment: Thank you for this extensive answer. Much appreciated.