# Better DB: performance and scalability wise for web application

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, web-applications, database

I am new to web development. I wanted to know what DB will be best suited for PHP for a requirement of Web Application. Till date i have worked with Oracle database and have found it bit slow for applications which need quick response time.

I was looking into MongoDB and MySQL and couldn't decide which to pick.

Please suggest which will be the best option also if any other option will be better suited.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends on your requirements. Just "quick response time" can't possibly be the only requirement.

Comment: there is no 'best'; and knowing nothing of your application we could only guess randomly

Comment: Best would be one that's tuned to your applications needs

Comment: You've not tuned Oracle, the hardware, or your queries correctly if it's "a bit slow". An Oracle DB server can be scaled massively. You shouldn't pick technology by asking "what's best." Like many things in life, best is highly subjective and the specific situation and environment must be considered. I'm surprised you accepted the first answer provided.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> I am **new to web development**. I wanted to know what DB will be best
>   suited for PHP for a requirement of Web Application. Till date i have
>   worked with Oracle database and have found it bit slow for
>   applications which need quick response time.

The answer is quite `subjective` as there are lot of factors need to be considered before jumping to a conclusion. I will lead you to **good articles** which can add some points in taking a decision.

1. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/22/designing-one-many-relations-mongodb-vs-mysql/
2. [mongoDB vs mySQL -- why one is better than another in some aspects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017010/mongodb-vs-mysql-why-one-is-better-than-another-in-some-aspects)
3. [MySQL vs MongoDB 1000 reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702643/mysql-vs-mongodb-1000-reads)

There is nothing called best, every technology has its own pros and cons. It all depends upon what you are comfortable in working with. **I would choose PHP/Java with MySQL anytime ahead of DOT NET with Sql Sever, just because i know the former well than latter.**

Comment: The question didn't ask anything about .NET, so I'm not sure why that was added, **in bold**?

Comment: @WiredPrairie: I was just giving an realistic example, that's all. nothing offense towards the language.

Comment: Your subjective answer would have been much better had it provided both a few links and some actual hands-on experience/recommendations with good evidence to back up each. As it is though, the question should be closed anyway.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: I take in this way developer comforts in working on a technology than evidence on which is faster. Both are equally good and has a cons and pros. As stated in last statement do in technology which you know well than doing all from scratch which also involves heavy learning. The links involve operations which will lead to to the OP a broad idea on the technical aspects involved in each than a plain old text-book benchmark article.

Comment: A scalable web app with PHP and MySQL? That mkes me kinda laugh if I am honest, you should see the problems facebook get from that setup

Comment: @Sammaye, please elaborate on ur comment. What kind of problems would i face using PHP with MySQL. and what should be better suited.?

Comment: @Sammaye: PHP is not dead, i think you need to look at Laravel or phalconphp these two new frameworks which drives the language in new direction... phalconphp is an extension based and its super fast.

Comment: @Vinothbabu I think you didn't quite understand me, laravel is even less scalable than PHP itself, the problem is fundamentally PHP

Comment: @Sammaye: I did construe your point and kinda know the scenes of Facebook story, but these frameworks have brought new life to PHP and a new set of direction. Just look at phalconphp which is an extension based framework, its just awesome. its installed as an extension that is always running so pages will load faster and is always running as a process.

Comment: @Vinothbabu Yes a core c extension is the way to go with frameworks in PHP but if you compare that extension to say python there would be no competition