# Can memcached be used to reduce the load on these SELECT * queries

Tags: php, mysql, apache, memcached

I have many users polling my php script on an apache server and the mysql query they run is a

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`>'example number'
```

Where example number can vary from user to user, but has a known lower bound which is updated every 10 minute.

The server is getting polled twice a second by each user.

Can memcache by used? It's not crucial that the user is displayed the most uptodate information, if it's a second behind or so that is fine.

The site has 200 concurrent users at peak times. It's hugely inefficient and costing a lot of resources.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you're trying to use the wrong tool for the job here.

memcached is a key/value storage, so you can make it store and retrieve several values with a given set of keys very quickly. However, you don't seem to know the keys you want in advance, since you're looking for all records where the id is **GREATER THAN** a number, rather than a collection of IDs. So, in my opinion, memcached won't be appropriate to use in your scenario.

Here are your options:

### Option 1: keep using MySQL and tune it properly

MySQL is quite fast if you tune it properly. You can:

- add the appropriate indexes to each table
- use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), which can help performance-wise in your case, as users are doing the same query over and over with different parameters
- use query caching

  Here's [a guide](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/) with some hints on MySQL tuning, and [mysqltuner](https://launchpad.net/mysqltuner), a Perl script that can guide you through the options needed to optimize your MySQL database.

### Option 2: Use a more advanced key-value storage

There are alternatives to memcached, with the most known one being [redis](http://redis.io/). redis does allow more flexibility, but it's more complex than memcached. For your scenario, you could use the redis [zrange](http://redis.io/commands/zrange) command to retrieve the results you want - have a look at the available [redis commands](http://redis.io/commands/) for more information.

### Option 3: Use a document storage NoSQL database

You can use a document storage [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database, with the most known example being [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).

You can use more complex queries in MongoDB (e.g. use operators, like "greater than", which you require) than you can do in memcached. [Here's an example of](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php) how to search through results in a mongo collection using operators (check example 2).

Have a look at the [PHP MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php) manual for more information.

Also, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476295/when-to-use-mongodb-or-other-document-oriented-database-systems) is an interesting read regarding document storage NoSQL databases.

Comment: that, espacially "the appropriate indexes to each table" (very important !). 200 users with twice request each a secon, that make 400 requests/s, tables with good indexes can handles (far !) more. And a better application design would be nice: when it's said "The server is getting polled twice a second by each user." AND "It's not crucial that the user is displayed the most uptodate information", it seems a bit incoherent.

Comment: Your option 1 advice is a bit odd. "Add the appropriate indexes" - yes, should be done, but there are queries that cannot use an index. "Prepared statements" will help nothing performancewise because PHP does destroy the db connection after the script was run. For one script run, there is one preparation and one data request - you gain nothing. "Use query caching" - I think you cannot actively use it, MySQL does it for you provided that the SQL is the same and the tables haven't changed. So the alternative is: DO use another cache for the whole query, and let it expire every 10 minutes.

Comment: Option 2 should also be commented on: Because you do not elaborate on why Memcached is "bad", there is no reason to use something "more advanced". I take this mention as "don't use memcache, use redis", but there is no explanation why. Option 3 changes the rules completely: Change the database. Throw away all your code that used MySQL, use MongoDB. And re-learn how to use NoSQL storages. That seems to be way off limits. The correct answer would be: Yes, Memcached might help you, and it is easy to apply. If you run into this matter more often, consider this: [options...]

Comment: @Sven: I clearly said that memcached isn't  a good solution here because the OP needs results with an ID greater than a number, and the max ID isn't known - this isn't straightforward to do with memcached, as it doesn't provide a way to search for results with greater than / less than operators. With memcached, this will need to be implemented by looking through all the keys, so memcached won't be an efficient solution here

Comment: But the query itself was considered cacheable by the OP. And that's what I'd expect here, too: Send the query to the database, get a result, and push it to Memcached with the query as the exact input for the key. Read back the result on the next request, and expire it in 10 Minutes.

Answer (score 1):

To give an accurate answer, I will need more information

1. Whether the query is pulling personalised information.
2. Whether the polling request got the 'example number' coming along with the request.

looking at the way you have structured your question , it doesn't seem like the user is polling for any personalised information. So I assume the 'example number' is also coming as a part of the polling request.

I agree to @roberttstephens and @Filippos Karapetis , That you can use ideal solutions

1. Redis
2. NoSQL
3. Tune the MySQL
4. Memcache

But as you guys have the application already out there in the wild, implementing above solutions will have a cost, so these are the practical solutions I would recommend.

1. Add indexes for your table wrt to relevant columns. [first thing to check /do]
2. Enable mysql query caching.
3. **Use a reverse proxy** - eg : varnish . [assumption 'example number' comes as a part of the request]

   - To intersect the requests even before it hits your application server so that the MySQL query , MemCache/ Redis lookup doesn't happen.
   - Make sure that you are setting specific cache headers set on the response so that varnish caches it.
   - So, of the 200 concurrent requests , if 100 of them are querying for same number varnish takes the hit. [it is the same advantage that memcache can also offer].
   - Implementation wise it doesn't cost much in terms of development / testing efforts.
   - I understand this is not the answer to the exact question . But I am sure this could solve your problem.
4. If the 'example number' doesn't come as a part of the request , and you have to fetch it from the DB [by looking at the user table may be..]  Then @roberttstephens approach is the way to go. just to give you the exact picture , I have refactored the code a little.
   `addServer('localhost', 11211);

   ```
   $inputNumber = 12345;
   $cacheKey = "poll:".$inputNumber;

   $result = $m->get($cacheKey);
   if ($result) {
       return unserialize($result);
   }

   $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT column1, column2 FROM poll WHERE id = $inputNumber");
   $sth->execute();
   $poll_results = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   $m->set($cacheKey, serialize($poll_results));`
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely use memcached to cache the results. You could instead create a cache table in mysql with less effort.

In either case, you would need to create an id for the cache, and retrieve the results based on that id. You could use something like entity_name:entity_id, or namespace:entity_name:entity_id, or whatever works for you.

Keep in mind, memcached is another service running on the server. You have to install it, set it up to start on reboot (or you *should* at least), allocate memory, etc. You'll also need php-memcached.

With that said, please view the php documentation on memcached. http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php . Assuming your poll id is 12345, you could use memcached like so.

```
<?php
// Get your results however you normally would.

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT column1, column2 FROM poll WHERE id = 12345");
$sth->execute();
$poll_results = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

// Set up memcached. It should obviously be installed, configured, and running by now.
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);

$m->set('poll:12345', serialize($poll_results));
```

This example doesn't have any error checking or anything, but this should explain how to do it. I also don't have a php, mysql, or memcached instance running right now, so the above hasn't been tested.

Comment: The OP clearly stated that he/she wants to find results where an ID is bigger than a number, and the max ID isn't known - this isn't straightforward to do with memcached. Your answer describes how to find an entry with a specific ID, which isn't what is required here

Comment: "Can memcache by used? It's not crucial that the user is displayed the most uptodate information, if it's a second behind or so that is fine."

He can absolutely cache is like poll:id, and have the application know that it's from a query that used > instead of =. He could decide how stale the data could be and implement it.