# Core Data Model Design

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, database-design

Let's assume I have an app about cooking recipes with two fundamental features:

1. The first one involves the CURRENT recipe that I'm preparing
2. The second one stores the recipes that I've decided to save

**STANDARD SCENARIO**

My current recipe is "Cheese Cake" and in `RecipeDetailViewController` I can see the current ingredients I've added for this recipe:

- Sugar
- Milk
- Butter
- etc.

Well, let's say that I'm satisfied from the final result and I decide to save (to log) the recipe I've just prepared.

* **click save** *

The recipe is now saved (is now logged) and in `RecipesHistoryViewController` I can see something like this:

- Nov 15, 2013 - Cheese Cake
- Nov 11, 2013 - Brownie
- etc.

Now if I want I can **edit** the recipe in the **history** and change Milk to Soy Milk, for example.

The issue it's that editing the recipe in the history **SHOULDN'T** edit the recipe (and its ingredients) in my current recipe and vice versa. If I edit the current recipe and replace Butter with Peanut Butter it must not edit anyone of the recipe stored in history. Hope I explained myself.

**CONSEQUENCES**

What this scenario implies? Implies that currently, for satisfing the function of this features, I'm duplicating the recipe and every sub-relationship (ingredients) everytime the user click on "Save Recipe" button. Well it works but I feel it can be something else more clean. With this implemention it turns out that I have TONS of different duplicates Core Data object (sqlite rows) like these:

- Object #1, name: Butter, recipe: 1
- Object #2, name: Butter, recipe: 4
- Object #3, name: Butter, recipe: 3

etc.

Ideas? How can I optimize this model structure?

**EDIT 1**

I've already thought of creating any **RecipeHistory** object with an attribute `NSString` where I could store a json dictionary but I don't know if it's better or not.

**EDIT 2**

Currently a `RecipeHistory` object contains this:

```
+-- RecipeHistory --+
|                   |
| attributes:       |
| - date            |
+-------------------+
| relationships:    |
| - recipes         |
+-------------------+

+----- Recipe ------+
| relationships:    |
| - recipeInfo      |
| - recipeshistory  |
| - ingredients     |
+-------------------+

+-- RecipeInfo  ----+
|                   |
| attributes:       |
| - name            |
+-------------------+

+--- Ingredient ----+
|                   |
| attributes:       |
| - name            |
+-------------------+
| relationships:    |
| - recipe          |
+-------------------+
```

paulrehkugler is true when he says that duplicating every `Recipe` object (and its relationships RecipeInfo and Ingredients) when I create a `RecipeHistory` is going to fill the database with a tons of data but I don't find another solution that allows me flexibility for the future. Maybe in the future I would to create stats about recipes and history and having Core Data objects could prove to be useful. What do you think? I think this is a common scenario in many apps that store history and allow to edit history item.

---

### BIG UPDATE

I have read the answers from some users and I want to explain better the situation.
The example I stated above is just an example, I mean that my app doesn't involve cook/recipe argument but I have used recipes because I think it's pretty okay for my real scenario.

Said this I want to explain that the app *NEEDS* two sections:
- First: where I can see the CURRENT recipe with related ingredients
- Second: where I can see the recipe I decided to save by tapping a button 'Save Recipe' in the first section

The current recipe found in the first section and a X recipe found in the 'history' section doesn't have NOTHING in common. However the user can edit whatever recipes saved in 'history' section (he can edit name, ingredients, whatever he wants, he can completely edit all things about a recipe found in history section).

This is the reason why I came up duplicating all `NSManagedObject`s. However, in this way, the database will grow as mad because everytime the user saves the current recipe the object representing the recipe (`Recipe`) is duplicated and also the relationships the recipes had (ingredients). So there will be TONS of ingredients named 'Butter' for example. You can say me: why the hell you need to have TONS of 'Butter' objects? Well, I need it because ingredients has for example the 'quantity' attribute, so every recipe have ingredients with different quantities.

Anyhow I don't like this approach, even it seems to be the only one. Ask me whatever you want and I'll try to explain every detail.

PS: Sorry for my basic English.

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: How open are you to a significant change of your persistence strategy?

Comment: The app isn't released yet. However before submitting your hyphotetical answer I'll suggest you reading the post update I'm gonna to make, I will add a lot of important details.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight just updated.

Comment: How many attributes does your real ingredient entity have then? And what role does that entity really play? Fabricated questions inevitably ignore details that are actually pertinent to an appropriate solution...

Comment: Wain I agree with you but it's very similar for this example. Made a quick update.

Comment: In the update section: if we have ingrediant, recipe, ingrediant-recipe tables why there would be TONS of 'Butter' objects? we will have just one 'Butter' and TONS of 'ingrediant-recipe' rows pointing to Butter. Is it correct?

Comment: No because every Ingredient has quantity stuff related. I've uploaded an image that explains the relationships.

Answer (score 7):

Since you must deal with history, and because the events are generated manually by end users, consider changing the approach: rather than storing the current view of the model entities (i.e. recipes, ingredients, and the connections among them) store the individual events initiated by the user. This is called [*Event Sourcing*](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html).

The idea is to record what user does, rather than recording the new state after the user's action. When you need to get the current state, "replay" the events, applying the changes to in-memory structures. In addition to letting you implement the immediate requirements, this would let you restore the state as of a specific date by "replaying" the events up to a certain date. This helps with audits.

You can do it by defining events like this:

- `CreateIngredient` - Adds new ingredient, and gives it a unique ID.
- `UpdateIngredient` - Changes an attribute of an existing ingredient.
- `DeleteIngredient` - Deletes an ingredient from the current state. Deleting an ingredient deletes it from all recipes and recipe histories.
- `CreateRecipe` - Adds a new recipe, and gives it a unique ID.
- `UpdateRecipeAttribute` - Changes an attribute of an existing recipe.
- `AddIngredientToRecipe` - Adds an ingredient to an existing recipe.
- `DeleteIngredientFromRecipe` - Deletes an ingredient from an existing recipe.
- `DeleteRecipe` - Deletes a recipe.
- `CreateRecipeHistory` - Creates a new recipe history from a specific recipe, and gives the history a new ID.
- `UpdateRecipeHistoryAttribute` - Updates an attribute of a specific recipe history.
- `AddIngredientToRecipeHistory` - Adds an ingredient to a recipe history.
- `DeleteIngredientFromRecipeHistory` - Deletes an ingredient from a recipe history.

You can store the individual events in a single table using Core Data APIs. Add a class that processes events in order, and creates the current state of the model. The events will come from two places - the event store backed by Core Data, and from the user interface. This would let you keep a single event processor, and a single model with the details of the current state of recipes, ingredients, and recipe histories.

> Replaying the events should happen only when the user consults the history, right?

No, that is not what happens: you read the whole history on start-up into the current "view", and then you send the new events both to the view and to the DB for persistence.

When users need to consult the history (specifically, when they need to find out how the model looked as of a specific date in the past) you need to replay the events partially, up until the date of interest.

Since the events are generated by hand, there wouldn't be too many of them: I would estimate the count in the thousands at the most - that's for a list of 100 recipes with 10 ingredients each. Processing an event on a modern hardware should be in microseconds, so reading and replaying the entire event log should be in the milliseconds.

> Furthermore, do you know any link that shows an example of how to use Event Sourcing in a Core Data application? [...] For example, should I need to get rid of RecipeHistory NSManagedObject?

I do not know of a good reference implementation for event sourcing on iOS. That wouldn't be too different from implementing it on other systems. You would need to get rid of all tables that you currently have, replacing it with a single table that looks like this:

[image: Event log entry]

The attributes would be as follows:

- `EventId` - Unique ID of this event. This is assigned automatically on insertion, and never changes.
- `EntityId` - Unique ID of the entity created or modified by this event. This ID is assigned automatically by a `Create...` processor, and never changes.
- `EventType` - A short string representing the name of this event type.
- `EventTime` - The time the event has happened.
- `EventData` - A serialized representation of the event - this can be binary or textual.

The last item can be replaced for a "denormalized" group of columns representing a superset of attributes used by the 12 event types above. This is entirely up to you - this table is merely one possible way of storing your events. It does not have to be Core Data - in fact, it does not even need to be in a database (although it makes things a little easier).

Comment: I'm a bit shocked about your reply. What's the advantage of that? However I've never used something similar and actually I don't even know where to start reyling on the current implementation in Core Data.

Comment: @FredCollins I've implemented temporal and bi-temporal models using both the copy-on-write approach that you are using and an event sourcing approach that I described in this answer. The event sourcing approach was significantly easier to implement correctly, and the resultant data model was much easier to maintain. Most importantly, copy-on-write approach generated a lot more duplication, and created issues when trying to audit records to see what happens when something goes wrong.

Comment: Replaying the events should happen only when the user consults the history, right? Furthermore, do you know any link that shows an example of how to use Event Sourcing in a Core Data application? That would be very appreciated for the reason that I've never used that. For example, should I need to get rid of `RecipeHistory` `NSManagedObject` ?

Comment: Altough I think I'm going to not implement this kind of answer in this application I'd like to say a big thank you and a +1 for introducing me to Event Sourcing, it seems interesting and I will try soon! Fred

Answer (score 4):

I think when a row in `RecipesHistoryViewController` is selected to modification, we can optimize the `Save` process with two options:

- Let the user chooses if a new row must be saved or an update may happen.
   Having a `Save New` button to create a new row in `Recipe` and an `Update` button to update the current selected row.
- To trace the changes have been made to a recipe (when update happens), I will try to log only changes of the recipe.
   Using [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) pattern will be an option.
  [image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]![enter image description here]
  As a hint:
   Comma separated values of ingredient name could be used as old and new values, when 
  inserting a row in RecipeHistory table, [the sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028547/ef-code-first-inherit-a-single-base-class-to-implement-easy-historocity/20029176#20029176) may helps.

About the **BIG UPDATE**:
Assuming that the real application have a database for persistent operation, some suggestions may be helpful.

> The current recipe found in the first section and a X recipe found in
>   the 'history' section doesn't have NOTHING in common

Leads the natural way of having no relation between `Current` and `In-History` recipe, so
trying to create a relation will be vain. With no relation the design will not be in normal form, redundancy will be inevitable.
Flowing the approach there will be many records, in the case

- We can limit any user's saved recipes in a predefined number.
- Another solution to optimize performance of recipe table would be [range
  partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29) the table based on creation date field (let a data
  base administrator be involved).
- Another suggestion is to have a separate table for ingredient
  concept.
   Having `ingredient`, `recipe`, `recipe-ingredient`
  tables will reduce redundancy.
  [image]

**Using NoSql**
*If relations are not trivial part of the applications logic*, I mean if your are not going to be ended in complex queries like "Which ingredients have been used more than X times in recipes that have less than total Y ingredients and Milk is not one of them" or analytical procedures then,have a look at [NoSql](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) databases and [comparison of them](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis). 
 
They offer being non-relational, distributed, open-source, schema-free, easy replication support, simple API, huge amount of data and horizontally scalable.

For a basic example of a document based database:
 Having [couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/) installed on my local machine(port number 5984) creating recipe database(table) on couchdb will be done by sending an standard HTTP request ([using curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)) like:

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/recipe
```

Dropping recipe table:

```
curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:5984/recipe
```

Adding a recipe:

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/recipe/myFirstRecipe -d 
'{"name":"Cheese Cake","description":"i am using couchDB for my recipes",
"ingredients": [ 
"Milk", 
"Sugar" 
],}'
```

Getting myFirstRecipe record(document)

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/recipe/myFirstRecipe
```

No need of classical server side process like object relation mapping, data base driver, etc 
BTW using Nosql will have short comings you need to consider, like [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-are-the-differences-between-nosql-and-a-traditional-rdbms) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476295/when-to-use-mongodb-or-other-document-oriented-database-systems).

Comment: Hi Mohsen Heydari and thanks for your answer. I have just made a big update to question. I can't apply your first suggestion because when the user is trying to 'save/log' the current recipe is certainly saving a NEW recipe, it will be certainly unique.

Comment: that. `With no relation the design will not be in normal form, redundancy will be inevitable.` it was what I ended too. By the way I've some doubts about `if not applicable having a partitioned table on creation date for recipe entity, will be helpful (let a DBA be involved)` what this means and what's DBA? Also, with `recipe-ingredient` you mean that I need to have an `Ingredient` inside a `Recipe` and every `Ingredient` is linked with a `IngredientInfo`? If that's can reduce the redundancy is better than nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Furthermore I will check your link about NoSql databases but first of all: do you see any advantage of using one of that in this scenario? (Also CoreData supports NoSql?)

Comment: Thanks man! Last question: why did you say that my application intends no relation?

Comment: Over all of our conversation and the design of the picture you have made of recipe and ingredient tables. As your real application is unknown to me, the suggestions are opinion base.

Comment: Yes but the picture I posted shows that recipe and ingredient have a relation between, I'm a bit confused about your statement 'intends no relation'. However I think this is the answer more appropriate to my scenario.

Comment: It is not about limited relation between entities, NOSql indeed suports collections, but the record and its collections have no dependency to other records or other entities, I made an update, hoping be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, your problem is more conceptual than model structure related.
My idea for your model is:

+***************+
Recipe
-----------------

-----------------
properties:
-----------------
- isDraft      - BOOL
- name         - NSString
- creationDate - NSDate
-----------------

-----------------
relationships:
-----------------
- ingredients - to-many with Ingredient
-----------------
+***************+

+***************+
Ingredient
-----------------

-----------------
properties:
-----------------
- name - NSString
-----------------

-----------------
relationships:
-----------------
- recipes - to-many with Recipe
-----------------

+***************+

Now, Lets call your "current" recipe a draft (a user may have many drafts).
As you can see, you can now display your recipes with a single fetched results controller (FRC)
The fetch request will look like this:

```
NSFetchRequest* r = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Recipe"];
[r setFetchBatchSize:25];

NSSortDescriptor* sortCreationDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
[r setSortDescriptors:@[sortCreationDate]];
```

you can section your data on the `isDraft` property:

```
NSFetchedResultsController* frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:r
                                                                      managedObjectContext:context
                                                                        sectionNameKeyPath:@"isDraft"
                                                                                 cacheName:nil];
```

Remember to give appropriate titles to your sections as to not confuse the user.

Now, all you have left is add some specific functionality like:

- create new recipe

  - save
  - save draft
- edit recipe (draft or not)

  - if draft offer to save as complete recipe
  - else, save the actual recipe
  - if you like, you might add a "save as" option
- create copy (the user is aware that he might introduce redundant data if he saves the same recipe more than once)

In any case the user experience should be consistent.
Meaning:
While the user is editing/adding an object, this object should not change "under his feet".
If a user is adding a new recipe, he then might wish to save it as draft, or as a complete recipe.
When he save, in either case, he might still wish to continue editing it. and so, no new object need be created.

If you like to add versioning for your recipes, you will need to add an entity like `RecipeHistory` related to a single recipe. this entity will record changes on each committed change in a complete recipe object (use `changedValues` of `NSManagedObject` or check against the existing/committed values).
You may serialise and store the data as you see fit.

So you can see, its more of a conceptual issue (how you access your data)  than it is a modelling issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few questions that need to be answered:

1. Is there a limit to the number of "history items" for a recipe or is it really necessary to keep **all** the versions of a recipe around?
2. When is a modification just a change of an existing recipe and when does the change result in a new recipe? For example, should the user be allowed to change a "cheese cake" recipe into a "meat loaf" recipe by completely replacing every ingredient and the title?

The answers to these questions are important when planing your data model. For example, ask yourself if this would be a valid use case for your app: The user creates a "Basic Cake" recipe that contains sugar, flour and eggs. The user now wants to take this "Basic Cake" recipe as a template to create a "Cheese Cake", a "Pound Cake" and a "Carrot Cake" recipe. Is that a valid use case?

If so, every time you save a recipe, it basically creates a completely new, independent recipe because the user is allowed to change **everything** and thus turn a cheese cake into a meat loaf.

However, I think that would be unexpected behavior for the user. In my opinion the user creates a "Cheese Cake" recipe and then might want to trace the changes to that one recipe and not turn it into something completely different.

This is what I would suggest:

1. Instead of a `RecipeHistory` owning `Recipes`, change your data model so that `Recipes` have multiple `RecipeVersions`. That way, users can explicitly create new recipes and then track the changes to that one recipe. Also, users would not be allowed to edit a `RecipeVersion` directly, but instead could "revert" their recipe to a specific version and then edit that.
2. Make `Ingredients` unique: "Butter", "Milk" and "Flour" exist exactly once in the database and are only references by the different recipes. That way, you will not have duplicates in your database and saving just the reference will take up less disk space than saving the name of the ingredient again and again.
3. Allow your users to create a new recipe based on an existing Recipe(Version). That way you give your users the ability to "base" a new recipe on an existing one without complicating your app and your data model.

This is my suggested data model:

```
+----- Recipe ------+
| attributes:       |
| - name            |
| relationships:    |
| - recipeVersions  |
+-------------------+

+-- RecipeVersion  ----+
| attributes:          |
| - timestamp          |
+----------------------+
| relationships:       |
| - recipe             | 
| - ingredients        |
+----------------------+

+--- Ingredient ----+
| attributes:       |
| - name            |
+-------------------+
| relationships:    |
| - recipeVersions  |
+-------------------+
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, btw I've updated the question with some details.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to duplicate all of the ingredient objects. Instead, just change the relationships so that recipes have many ingredients and ingredients can be in many recipes. Then when you create a duplicate recipe you just connect to the existing ingredients.

This would also make it easier to list the recipes that use an (or some combination of) ingredients.

You should also consider your UI/UX - should it be a full duplicate? Or should you allow the user to create 'alternatives' within each recipe (which just list a set of replacement ingredients).

Comment: Hi Wain and thanks for your answer. I have just made a big update to question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tradeoff between storage size and retrieval time.

If you duplicate each recipe every time the user clicks the "Save Recipe" button, you duplicate a lot of data in the database.

If you create a RecipeHistory object that has a Recipe and a list of changes, it takes longer to retrieve the data and populate your View Controllers, because you have to reconstruct a full Recipe in memory.

I'm not sure which is easier - whichever suits your use case is probably best.

Comment: Check my update to see what a `RecipeHistory` object contains.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I am clear on the problem you are trying to solve but I would start by modelling the Recipe and Ingredients and keep them separate from the actual mix and method which may change as the cook experiments. With some smart application logic you could only track the changes in each version rather than make a new copy.  For example if the user decides to try a new version of a recipe then by default show the previous versions (or allow the user to select a version) Method and RecipeIngredients and if any changes are made save these changes as new Method and RecipeIngredient associated with the RecipeVersion.

This approach will use less storage but requires much more complicated application logic, for example swapping an ingredient would setting the quantity to 0 for the ones being replaced and adding new records for the new ones.  Simply duplicating the previous (or user selected) version is not going to use much space, these are small records, and will be much much simpler to implement.

[image]

Comment: This model can still accommodate your requirements. You can partition things into your two Sections by using version numbers or simply include a flag on the mixVersion indicating whether it is the Current Version.  All others then appear in the history section.

Comment: Well actually in the real scenario it doesn't make very sense have the object and its multiple "revisions/versions" because everyone it's unique.

Comment: OK well I am confused then by what you mean with History because history implies some relationship between the History objects and the current object (and usually its change over time with the current object being the current preferred version, for whatever purpose). They are all still unique objects and can be independently copied, saved, edited, deleted, etc.. Of course if you start editing a version then does this need to go into its own history or does it become the current version or what?

Comment: In any event bear in mind that you may have two recipes for Cheese Cake and similarly you may have Cheese (an ingredient) in more that one recipe so your model (Recipe <-->>Ingredient) forces you to create a new ingredient called cheese for each recipe.  In the model above you only ever have to create one Ingredient called Cheese and for each Recipe you use Cheese in you create a record that defines only the quantity to be used, which is probably unique to that recipe.

Comment: Try this book for lots of examples of modelling objects http://www.amazon.com/Java-Modeling-Color-With-UML/dp/013011510X

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be better to define ingredient table to have ingredientID and ingredientDisplayName, and in recipie history table store RecipieID, HistoryDate, IngredientArray.

if in ingredient table,
id:1 is Butter
id:2 is Milk
id:3 is cheese
id:4 is Sugar
id 5 is Soymilk

then in history table
for recipe 1: Cheese Cake, data Nov 15, IngredientArray: {1,2,3,4}
if on Nov 16 Cheese cake changes to have soy milk instead of milk then on that date IngredientArray is {1,2,3,5} . Many database has array column option or alternately could be a comma separated string or a Json document.
Its better to keep the ingredient list in-memory to do fast lookup to get ingredient names from list.

Answer (score 1):

maybe I did not understand your question, but do you need to change the name of butter by editing? Why not just delete butter from that one recipe and add peanut butter to it. That way you do not change butter to peanut butter for al your other recipes that are linked to it? And with new recipes you can select peanut butter or butter.

Comment: Yea but the big issue is the need of duplicating every object and its relationships when a 'Recipe' is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, we are talking about frontend?

First, like suggest by Mohsen Heydari, on SQL rdbms, you should create a table between many-to-many connections to make two one to many for performance.

So you want a historic

```
+-- RecipeHistory --+
|                   |
| attributes:       |
| - id              |
| - date            |
| - new name?       |
| - notes ??        |
| - recipe-id       |
+-------------------+
| relationships:    |
| - recipes         |
+-------------------+

+----- Recipe ------+
| attributes:       |
| - id              |
| - name            |
| - discription     |
| - date            |
| - notes           | #may be useful?
| - Modifiable      | #this field is false if in history, else true,
+-------------------+
| relationships:    |
| recipe-ingredient |
+-------------------+

+-Recipe-ingridient-+
| attributes:       |
| id                |
| recipe-id         |
| ingridient-id     |
| quantity          |
+-------------------+

+--- Ingredient ----+
|                   |
| attributes:       |
| - id              |
| - name            |
+-------------------+
| relationships:    |
| -recipe-ingredient|
+-------------------+
```

Now if modifiable field on Recipe = True it belongs on the MainPage

If its false, it belongs on the historic page

After finding a recipe you want, you can query the ingredients by its recipe-id using the Recipe-Ingredient table, or Recipe by Ingredients the same way.

Another option less space hungry would be create a Recipe history, and create a Modified recipe table -> which takes a base recipe ID,

And map it to -> Main Recipe ID, Discarded Ingredients and New Ingredients, if you want this solution explained just ask