# Using concrete classes or liquid classes for attributes

Tags: database, oop, database-design, data-structures

I mean, by liquid classes like having Attribute.java

```
String name;
Object Value;
Long entityId;
```

And implementing User.java like:

```
Set<Attribute> attributes;
Long id;
```

Or Concrete classes implementation of User.java

```
String realName;
String displayedName;
Int score;    
Long id;
```

Which one  is effective by database concepts and OOP concepts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on to the problem domain you are trying to solve.
If you are going to use liquid approach ([Entity–attribute–value_model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)) on a problem like [logging other entities changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028547/ef-code-first-inherit-a-single-base-class-to-implement-easy-historocity/20029176#20029176), that would be a good approach.
If the EVA approaches is going to be applied on relational data model that JOINs are inevitable part of queries, using EVA would be an anti pattern.